# Better way to get a full array from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Ive started working alot with arrays and I'm finding they are ace!!!  I have a simple question about how best to build my array straight from a query.

Im using Object code and mysqli, so here is a simple query I have to get me all users in the DB....

```
 public function getUser($iduser)
 {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = $this->db->query($this->db->link, $query);

   if($this->db->num_rows($result)>0)
   {
     return $this->db->fetch_assoc($result);
   }
   return 'NULL';
 }
```

now I can do a "do while" loop and loop through all these records however id like them as an array so I changed my query to......

```
 public function getUser($iduser)
 {
    $finalArray = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);

   if($this->db->num_rows($result)>0)
   {
     while($row = $this->db->fetch_assoc($result))
     {
         array_push($finalArray, $row);
     }
   }

  return $finalArray;
 }
```

My question is with the second option is this the most efficient way of doing this or is there a better faster way that uses less resources and code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Arrays might be "ace" but beware of how much memory they take

Comment: You can use this mysqli function mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

That's more efficient.  Also be aware arrays use a good amount of memory if you're planning on increasing speed and efficiency it's unwise to go array crazy